# routerLink and separate function in the same ion-item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

In Ionic 5, I have a `ion-list` with multiple `ion-item`. Each `ion-item` has a `rotuerLink` and some text. They also have an `ion-button` inside, which should execute some other function. The problem is that when I click that button, the app executes the function but also navigates me to the link. Is there any way to disable this?

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let stop of stops" routerLink="/stops/{{stop.id}}">
    <div class="main-text">
      {{stop.address}}
    </div>
    <ion-button slot="end" (click)="onNavigate(stop.address)">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="navigate"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: can you move that routerLink from ion-item to one of its child

Comment: Seems like a bad structure. You don't want a clickable parent element to have a clickable child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `(click)="onNavigate(stop.address, $event)"`

And then stop propagation with `$event.stopPropagation()`